# Не работают custom taxonomy wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Помогите пожалуйста решить проблему

Есть кастомный тип записи catalog, slug - catalog

Есть кастомная таксономия cars, slug - cars, hierarchical - true

есть файл taxonomy-cars.php

есть плагин Custom Post Type Permalinks
в настройках указан формат ссылки site.com/catalog/%cars%

если например открыть саму запись по ссылке `site.com/catalog/cars/car-cat-1/item` то все нормально работает

но, если открыть `site.com/catalog/cars/car-cat-1/` получаю 404, страница не найдена

а если ссылка будет `site.com/catalog/cars/` в браузере меняется на `site.com/catalog/%cars%` с ошибкой 400 Bad Request

в чем может быть проблема и как можно решить?

```
function cars_post_texonomy() { 
    register_taxonomy('cars',
        array('catalog'),
        array(
            'hierarchical' => true,
            
            'labels' => array(
            
                'name' => 'Категории для машин',
                'singular_name' => 'Категории',
                'search_items' =>  'Найти Категории',
                'popular_items' => 'Популярные Категории',
                'all_items' => 'Все Категории',
                'parent_item' => null,
                'parent_item_colon' => null,
                'edit_item' => 'Редактировать Категорию', 
                'update_item' => 'Обновить Категорию',
                'add_new_item' => 'Добавить новую Категорию',
                'new_item_name' => 'Название новой Категорию',
                'separate_items_with_commas' => 'Разделяйте Категорию запятыми',
                'add_or_remove_items' => 'Добавить или удалить Категорию',
                'choose_from_most_used' => 'Выбрать из наиболее часто используемых Категорий',
                'menu_name' => 'Категории для машин'
            ),
            'public' => true, 
            'show_in_nav_menus' => true,
            'show_ui' => true,
            'default_term' => array('name' => 'none', 'slug' => 'none', 'description' => ''),
            'show_tagcloud' => true,
            'update_count_callback' => '_update_post_term_count',
            'query_var' => true,
            'rewrite' => array(
                'slug' => 'cars', 
                'hierarchical' => true
 
            )
        )
    );
}
add_action( 'init', 'cars_post_texonomy', 0 );
```

```
add_action( 'init', 'true_register_post_type_init' ); 
 
function true_register_post_type_init() {
    $labels = array(
        'name' => 'Каталог',
        'singular_name' => 'Каталог', // админ панель Добавить->Функцию
        'add_new' => 'Добавить ',
        'add_new_item' => 'Добавить новый ', // заголовок тега <title>
        'edit_item' => 'Редактировать ',
        'new_item' => 'Новый ',
        'all_items' => 'Все ',
        'view_item' => 'Просмотр на сайте',
        'search_items' => 'Искать ',
        'not_found' =>  'Ничего не найдено.',
        'not_found_in_trash' => 'В корзине пусто.',
        'menu_name' => 'Каталог' 
    );
    $args = array(
        'labels' => $labels,
        'public' => true,
        'show_ui' => true, // показывать интерфейс в админке
        'has_archive' => 'catalog',
        'taxonomies' => array('cars'),
        'hierarchical' => false,
        'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-location-alt', 
        'menu_position' => 20, 
        'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => "catalog", 'with_front' => false),
        'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'comments', 'author', 'thumbnail')
    );
    register_post_type('catalog', $args);
}
```

Comment: Покажи твой код кастомных сущностей

Comment: добавил код таксономий